# Clearing service worker cache if user deletes cookies manually

Tags: service-worker, workbox, service-worker-events

I'm currently using Workbox to get some caching done with Service Workers. Right now, I'm facing the issue of removing more personalised data from the cache when the user logs out. We have already implemented this by posting a message to the SW upon the logout action. However, I'm having trouble handling the edge case where the user deletes the cookies. Because of how we do authentication, the user is logged out upon cookie deletion. But we are unable to detect this deletion and thus unable to clear the cache.

Any suggestions on how to handle edge case or to better handle authenticated assets in SW/Workbox? Thanks!

Below is a short example of our current flow.

```
* sw.js */
self.addEventListener("message", msg => {
  if (msg.type) {
    switch (msg.event) {
      case "LOGOUT":
        // delete caches which contain personalized data
        Promise.all(
          exprPlugins.map(plugin =>
            plugin.deleteCacheAndMetadata(),
          ),
        )
        // ... other code
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ideally you should not have any PII information stored in cache.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking this in a too SW specific way I guess :-)

Pseudocode:

```
// Page loads / timer fires every one minute
// if (no cookie found) 
//  -- send logout msg to sw
// else 
//  -- send "the user logged in is *id from cookie*" kinda event
//  -- sw checks the data matches whoever is now logged in and if needed purges the cache
```

Please note that since this is not an automatic event after the cookie is manually deleted, an ill-meaning user could open Dev Tools and look at the data from the previous user. Thus this is *NOT SECURE*, it's more like a tongue-in-the-cheek workaround.

As others pointed out, you should probably not be caching any critical PII info into the caches.

Comment: Hey @pate, thanks for the tip! However, wouldn't this constant polling be quite expensive? or should I do something like exponential backoff in this case?

Comment: Happy to help :-) No, that wouldn't be expensive at all. What I was referring to was something like setInterval or recursive setTimeout every 60 seconds or so. The other possibility, even better one, would be to check the cookie status on evey page load. You could also check it every time the tab is focused. But once again, don't put anything sensitive in there.